# Can't properly parse JSON

Tags: java, android, json, mobile

I am having some issues while parsing JSON response in Android. The response I get is:

```
{

"response": "{\"session_token\":\"48500d8e42acc09aa45cb8f3a7ba2b30\",\"user_login\":\"newoff2\",\"user_id\":\"62\",\"user_profile_img\":\"http://onepgr.com/system/photos/62/medium/userfile054c35e29.png?1422089771\",\"success\":\"0\",\"user_email\":\"newoff2@pdmoffice.com\"}"

}
```

I need the values for `user_login`, `success`, `user_profile_img`, `user_email`. Here is what I tried so far, but it won't do what I need:

```java
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
// write response to log
Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
String json = reader.readLine();

Log.d("Final Response",json);


jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
JSONObject json1=jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
String str = json1.getString("success");
Log.e("Parsed data is",str);
```

Comment: your json response is in wrong format

Comment: I know bro ,,, but how to decode it .. cause its from client and cant be changed @Ravi

Comment: just replace \" with "

Comment: it should be something like this {

         "response": {"session_token":"48500d8e42acc09aa45cb8f3a7ba2b30","user_login":"newoff2","user_id":"62","user_profile_img":"http://onepgr.com/system/photos/62/medium/userfile054c35e29.png?1422089771","success":"0","user_email":"newoff2@pdmoffice.com"}

         }

Comment: yaa Ravi but .. i just have api not anything else from client side

Answer (score 1):

Use `Scanner` to remove `\`:

```
String resultStr = new Scanner(json).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
jsonObject = new JSONObject(resultStr);
```

Above is used for `BufferedInputStream` to get JSON string.

[**UPDATE:**]

For `BufferReader`, need to use `StringBuilder` to get JSON string:

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

 String line;
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    strBuilder.append(line);
}

//for your JSON string, should use 'JSONTokener' to parse
jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(strBuilder.toString()).nextValue();
JSONObject json1=jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
String str = json1.getString("success");
```

This should work for your case!

Comment: thnks for reply .. let me try this .. :)

Comment: Response﹕ {"response":"{\"session_token\":\"09b210402c75b2900c77b5b5e486d836\",\"user_login\":\"newoff2\",\"user_id\":\"62\",\"user_profile_img\":\"http://onepgr.com/system/photos/62/medium/userfile054c35e29.png?1422089771\",\"success\":\"0\",\"user_email\":\"newoff2@pdmoffice.com\"}"}

Comment: W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value {"session_token":"09b210402c75b2900c77b5b5e486d836","user_login":"newoff2","user_id":"62","user_profile_img":"http://onepgr.com/system/photos/62/medium/userfile054c35e29.png?1422089771","success":"0","user_email":"newoff2@pdmoffice.com"} at response of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject


System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
    json=json.replace("\\\"", "\"");
    Log.e("resule",json);
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thnks .. let me try it out

Comment: Expected literal value at character 13

Comment: E/resule﹕ {"response":{\"session_token\":\"835eb24945d16aec029b90b6012f0059\",\"user_login\":\"newoff2\",\"user_id\":\"62\",\"user_profile_img\":\"http://onepgr.com/system/photos/62/medium/userfile054c35e29.png?1422089771\",\"success\":\"0\",\"user_email\":\"newoff2@pdmoffice.com\"}}

Comment: W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 13 of {"response":{\"session_token\":\"835eb24945d16aec029b90b6012f0059\",\"user_login\":\"newoff2\",\"user_id\":\"62\",\"user_profile_img\":\"http://onepgr.com/system/photos/62/medium/userfile054c35e29.png?1422089771\",\"success\":\"0\",\"user_email\":\"newoff2@pdmoffice.com\"}}

Comment: Unterminated object at character 16 of

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex to make your string JSON parsable

```
var res = data.replace(/\\"/g, '').replace(/\"{/g, '{').replace(/\}"/g, '}');
var jsonData = JSON.parse(res);
alert(jsonData.response.user_login);
```

Here is [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishkumar9211/v5wpqqqm/)

Note: in fiddle I have declared your JSON with a ' ' to make it complete string

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this....

InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        // json is UTF-8 by default
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        result = sb.toString();

        Log.d("Result",result);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String resJson=jsonObject.getString("response");
        Log.d("Result",resJson);
        JSONObject jsparam=new JSONObject(resJson);
        String success=jsparam.getString("success");

        Log.d("Value for success",success);
        // JSONObject json1=jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
        //String objResponse = json1.getString("success");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Oops
    }
    finally {
        try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
    }
```